# React get with axios request shows incorrect data from the api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I have an axios GET request on my react application to get data from my express hosted api what happened is when I try it from postman this is the result

```
{
    "totalRegistered": 13
}
```

and is the correct value
but when requesting from my react app it displays as 52

[image]

I have not added or done any math on the react side , I've only displayed the data from the api
I've also checked out a console log its also showing the value 52.
This is only happening on values returned as a number(integer, double...)
`

```
class vehicles extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        total_registered: null,
    }
}
async componentDidMount() {
    const total_registered = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/app/vehicles'
    await axios.get(total_registered, {
        'key': [
            "totalPortRegistered",
            "total"
        ]
    }).
        then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            self.setState({ total_registered: response.data })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
            if (self.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
                notify.show('Cannot Fetch Data! Network Error', "error");
            }
        })
}
render() {
    return (
        < div className="card elevation p-5 m-2" >
            <center>
                <h3>{this.state.total_registered ? this.state.total_registered.totalPortRegisteredVehicles : <ReactLoading type={"bubbles"} color={"#000000"} height={20} width={20} />}</h3>
                <p>Total Vehicles</p>
            </center>

        </div >
    );
}
}`
```

Comment: can you add the code for vehicles component ?

Comment: i've edited it above ,please check it out

Comment: What is the console.log(response) show in your axios then response? Based on the output I'm seeing I assume that what you see in the browser is the this.state.total_registered.totalPortRegisteredVehicles and not the this.state.total_registered.

Comment: the console log shows
{
totalPortRegisteredVehicles: 52
}